# ZendFramework 3 PUT method parameters access

Tags: zend-framework3

I make REST API service based on Zend Framework 3. I stuck on a moment where I should process PUT request. Let it be like this:

```
PUT /document/14
Request parameters are: {
    token: '.. some string here ..',
    name: '....',

}
```

The thing is, that I can't even get "token", because neither $this->getRequest()->getQuery() nor $this->getPost() don't contain any parameters at all.

I've seen few recommendations like registering Zend_Controller_Plugin_PutHandler, but I didn't find such class in Zend Framework 3.

Comment: Are you using AbstractRestfulController (as you are actually supposed to do)  
OR 
AbstractActionController and trying to catch post data?

Comment: ... AbstractActionController and trying to catch post data as in $this->params()->fromPost('token', false)?

Comment: I use AbstractRestfulController and ->fromPost('token', false) gives empty result.

Comment: SO doesn't send notification if poster's name is not mentioned in the reply (unless you are the original poster), so I didn't see your reply. Regarding your question: You are supposed to be using create($data) function of AbstractRestfulController to catch POST requests. And $data parameter contains your POST variables. $data['token'] is your token post value. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get JSON data, and there is no params helper for that, so fast hack would be:

```
// In your Controller action
$content = $this->getRequest()->getContent();
$data    = json_decode($content, true);

var_dump($data); // here you will have your json as array
```

This works but a better way is to use [AbstractRestfulController](https://zendframework.github.io/zend-mvc/controllers/#abstractrestfulcontroller). 
Extend it and you will have automatically $id and $data injected in the method **update($id, $data)**. Also you will have all other methods for RESTful API.

You should check implementation of that class for more info, especially method [jsonDecode](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-mvc/blob/master/src/Controller/AbstractRestfulController.php#L621)

Comment: You've helped me a little bit. But I don't need to decode json data, because ->getContent() gave me multipart form-data. So I have another question. Is there any embedded ZF3 method to decode such hell of a code? :)

Comment: Your request is a JSON as you ask in a question? Can you please edit the question above.. because something is a different from your comment here...